# Physical interpretation of the magic of functional derivatives in QM and QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, correlation-functions

In the path integral formalism, the correlation function can be derived by taking the functional derivative to the generating functional.

In quantum mechanics, for example, we have
$$
\frac{1}{\mathrm i}\frac{\delta}{\delta f(t)} \frac{1}{\mathrm i}\frac{\delta}{\delta f(t')}\langle q'',t_2|q',t_1 \rangle^f = \langle q'',t_2|T\left\{\hat Q(t)\hat Q(t')\right\}|q',t_1 \rangle^f,
$$
where the superscript $f$ indicates that the dynamics is augmented with an *external force*, and the Lagrangian reads $L=L_0+f(t)q(t)$, leading to a "force term" in the path integral.

This procedure is clear, but I have some questions:

1. What's the relation between external forces (or *source terms*  $J(\phi)$ in QFT) and the correlation functions? For me, they seem to be totally irrelevant.
2. Furthermore, is there any **physical interpretation** or intuition of this method? Or it's just a mathematical trick that happens to be a useful trick (which is how I understand it now, but I hope it's not the final answer)?